# Postgres join tables with certain requirements

Tags: python, postgresql

I've been trying to create a certain query through flask for a project needed at work. The idea is to create a client management system whereupon providing the name of the client the code returns a table with all the information. What I did was create one table called clients where I store name, address, etc, and another table called maintenance where there I store issues dates and name, just these three columns. what I am hoping to achieve is to return upon input of the client's name one row with has the client's information and another row hat displays only issues and date.

```
SELECT
    clients.name,
    clients.vat,
        clients.address,
    clients.phone,
        clients.plate,
    clients.year,
        clients.vin,
    clients.engine,
        clients.email,
    maintenance.issue,
    maintenance.date
FROM
    clients
INNER JOIN maintenance ON clients.plate = maintenance.plate
where clients.name = 'PETROS'
```

this code works ok inside pgadmin4
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bklj.png)

but when I run it in flask and display it with an HTML table I get as expected multiple tables also.
the idea was something like this.
[omit all the duplicate info and just keep the issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nwjE.png)

And this is the HTML code for displaying the info

```
        <div id="sectionE" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Καρτέλα</h3>
          <form name = "search" form method="post" action="/client_card">
            <p><label for="search">Αναζητηση Πελατη</label></p>
            <p><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Ονοματεπωνυμο.." name = "NAME" onkeyup="var start = this.selectionStart;var end = this.selectionEnd;this.value= this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(start, end);"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Αναζητηση">
         </form>
         <br>
         <table id="results_customer">
          <tr>
          {% for row in data4 %}
          <h3>Στοιχεια</h3>
            <th>Ονομα</th>
            <th>ΑΦΜ</th>
            <th>Διευθηνση</th>
            <th>Τηλεφωνο</th>
            <th>e-mail</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[8]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="results_customer">
          <h3>Στοιχεια Οχηματος</h3>
          <tr>
            
            <th>Πινακιδα </th>
            <th>Μοντελο</th>
            <th>Χρονολογια</th>
            <th>Πλαισιο</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[5]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[6]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[7]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="results_customer">
          <h3>Εργασιες και Σχολια</h3>
          <tr>

            <th>Εργασιες</th>
            <th>Ημερομηνια</th>
          </tr>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word"></tdstyle>>{{row[9]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[10]}}</td>

          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          
</table>
          </div>
```

The way things are i just get three times the same table. and if i add more issues it will just keep multiplying.
Sorry for the long post ive been trying with anything i can find but no luck.The other option is to make two separate queries through python or join then through sql. any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your `clients` and `maintenance` table's sample data and also your expected data ?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand! do you want to see what happens with this query and what I would like to happen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried out a few things and well I quess that works to my liking. although I would still want to find out if there is a proper way to do it through postgres

```
def client_card():
    NAME = request.form["NAME"]
    query = ('''SELECT * from clients where NAME = %s ''')
    cur.execute(query,(NAME,))
    results_customer = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    query_1 = ('''select maintenance.issue,maintenance.date
                from maintenance, clients
                where maintenance.plate = clients.plate AND
                clients.name= %s''')
    cur.execute(query_1,(NAME,))
    results_is = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    return render_template("choices.html", data4 = results_customer,data5 = results_list)
```

so basically one way is to query another table and view its output but that only works through python

```
select maintenance.issue,maintenance.date
from maintenance, clients
where maintenance.plate = clients.plate AND clients.name= %s
```

and I just created another table in the HTML form to view these results below the first query

```
 <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" id="results_is">
     <h3>Εργασιες και Σχολια</h3>
       <tr>
        <th>Εργασιες</th>
        <th>Ημερομηνια</th>
       </tr>
{% for row in data5 %}

        <tr>
          <td style="word-wrap: break-word">{{row[0]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[1]}}</td> 
         </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```